# Has a healing miracle ever been recorded on camera?

Tags: history, miracles, healing, technology

Simple question: has a healing miracle ever been recorded on camera? I'm open to answers from any Christian groups/denominations.

Comment: Just a simple clarification. By camera do you mean a simple still photo?

Comment: @KenGraham: technically speaking that would be a valid particular case.

Comment: As always: dear down-voter, would you kindly share the reasons for your downvote? Any suggestions to correct the flaws that you see in the question?

Comment: I see no reason to downvote this question, but nevertheless I  personally avoid asking reasons for it. People are people and that will not change things. I suggest that you be mature enough to take the hit! Sometimes I sense individuals fear a verifiable answer. It is that simple.

Comment: @KenGraham - People may sometimes have legitimate reasons to downvote, and I see that feedback as a valuable opportunity to improve my question writing skills.

Comment: For those who believe that we can expect faith-healing in our day, I would like to know where were the faith healers during the Covid-19 pandemic? Would have been great to in that case put a stop to that dang pandemic or at least go around and help out at the hospitals. After all Jesus healed many people and there is not a single case where the BIble says that Jesus was unable to heal someone.

Comment: @coderworks - Matthew 13: *57 And they took offense at him. But Jesus said to them, “A prophet is not without honor except in his own town and in his own home.” 58 **And he did not do many miracles there because of their lack of faith**.*

Comment: @coderworks Given that vastly more people have died from other things during that time frame, where were the faith healers for all those other causes of death (cancer, heart disease, car accidents, Alzheimer's, ...)?

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator, that was not a case where Jesus was **unable** to perform miracles, meaning it was not the kind of thing where he **tried to** but was somehow blocked by "lack of faith". Consider John 5:5-9, 13 where Jesus healed a lame man who did not even know who Jesus was, and Luke 22:50, 51 where he restored the severed ear of the high priest’s servant, although that man was one of the group of Jesus’ enemies who had come to arrest him. Jesus also resurrected dead people who could not have displayed faith (Luke 8:54, 55; John 11:43, 44).

Comment: @OneGodtheFather, that is a good point too. I do not believe in faith healing but just wanted to challenge any who think that someone is currently able to do such.

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator Do you mean something captured on camera that was *claimed* to be a healing? What exactly do you have in mind here?

Comment: @coderworks - Matthew 17: *19 Then came the disciples to Jesus apart, and said, **Why could not we cast him out**? 20 And Jesus said unto them, Because of your unbelief: for verily I say unto you, If ye have faith as a grain of mustard seed, ye shall say unto this mountain, Remove hence to yonder place; and it shall remove; and nothing shall be impossible unto you. 21 **Howbeit this kind goeth not out but by prayer and fasting**.*

Comment: @OneGodtheFather - that's one option, but ideally I would like a visible ailment/disease getting healed on camera, such as a severe case of scoliosis getting healed, where you see the person having their back straightened, etc.

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator, the example from Matthew 17:19 is a case of faith being needed on the part of the healer (in this case the apostles), not on the part of the sick/possessed person.

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator How do you understand what defines a miracle, here?

Comment: @OneGodtheFather - it's kind of hard to give a formal definition of what constitutes a healing miracle, but my attempt would be some kind of spontaneous healing that "shouldn't have happened" according to our current understanding of biology and physics.

Comment: @OneGodtheFather - talking about contemporary evidence of gifts of healing, did you have the chance to see [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/83873/50422)?

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator re other question, bookmarked!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Lot's of them. I have collected some links to miracles reported online on my blog. A number of the links point to videos, and some of those show people being ministered to and indicating that the health problem is no longer there. My favorite is [of a man healed of back problems](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6KnLDsq4XXA) he has suffered from for years. I just love how he responds.

However, when it comes to miracles, it is not a lack of historical or contemporary examples that is the problem. Rather, it our cultural predisposition to anti-supernaturalism. I have found Professor [Craig Keener](https://craigkeener.com/)'s work in this area particularly helpful, especially his two volume work *[Miracles: The Credibility of the New Testament Accounts.](https://www.christianbook.com/miracles-credibility-new-testament-accounts-vols/craig-keener/9780801039522/pd/039522?event=ESRCG)* If you don't have time or motivation to read a two volume work, there are a number of videos of his lectures on the topic online.

Comment: Nice find, but have these been medically verified by medical professionals, such as doctors? YouTube videos are fine, but this site requires verifiable evidence.

Comment: Is the YouTube channel you linked to your blog? If not, can you include a link to your blog?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259).

Comment: Ken Graham, the question was have any miracles been caught on camera, not have they been caught on camera and then medically verified. However, if that's what you need (there are plenty of medically verified miracles listed in Keener's book, but most were not also captured on camera) there's Delia Knox (https://marcustutt.wordpress.com/2010/11/24/the-continuing-testimony-of-delia-knox/) and an audio of a healing of Duane Miller's voice (https://youtu.be/IHE16szuoGU?t=2468).

Comment: The medical documentation for Duane Miller's healing is detailed in Lee Strobel's excellent book, "The Case for Miracles," but he also outlines it in the video starting here: https://youtu.be/IHE16szuoGU?t=2819

Comment: Makes me think of the charismatic faith healers in a 3rd world country that have at times even "resurrected" someone (someone who was not dead in the first place). All in an effort to garner support for the preacher who lives in luxury, of course.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the only denomination that has laid out the conditions for such a phenomenon is the Catholic Church, which requires:

- the healing must be “complete”,
- “instantaneous”, and
- “durable”, as well as
- “scientifically inexplicable”.

The "instantaneous" criterion combined with "scientifically inexplicable" implies that this phenomenon occurs as the subject is under measurable  observation prior to, during, and after the phenomenon without interruption of measuring.

From a scientific POV, the subject should also not be receiving treatment in the form of medication, irradiation, or other techniques, as that would render the effect "scientifically explicable".

A phenomenon adhering to these conditions has never been recorded (either on still images or video, or otherwise documented in a scientifically undeniable way). And even that would not rule out the [placebo effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placebo#Effects) or [spontaneous remission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_remission).

Comment: I've heard stories of bone fractures being spontaneously healed, which cannot be explained away as placebo effect or spontaneous remission (I mean, bone fractures normally take months to heal, not seconds). Unfortunately, there are no video recordings to back up those stories as far as I'm aware, only the testimony of the alleged eyewitnesses.

Comment: According to a [NIH study](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/12463652/): "Fractures may heal spontaneously in spite of gross instability while minimal, even non-visible, instability may be deleterious for rigidly fixed small fracture gaps. The theory of strain offers an explanation for the maximum instability which will be tolerated and the minimal degree required for induction of callus formation." - most likely the alleged eyewitnesses did not observe actual bone healing (if so, how?), but the person being able to stand or use their broken limb.

Comment: What about [scoliosis](https://youtu.be/jcL8WNTx6mk)?

Comment: I heard of one case being photographed at the moment of healing, but I can not track it down. The photo in question shows a young man dropping his crutches at that exact moment.

Comment: @KenGraham, but what about the *next* moment?   [Faith healer visits a small town](https://www.reddit.com/r/Jokes/comments/22ct74/faith_healer_visits_a_small_town/) — strong language warning.

Answer (score 0):

I personally witnessed one of these healing miracles.  The lady who was healed came to our prayer meeting that evening needing help to come in, as she was unable to walk on her own.  She was not paralyzed, but her legs were impaired in some way that made her lame--a condition which she had had for some time.

I was uncomfortable with how the meeting progressed, to be honest.  Usually, when we would pray together, one person would pray at a time--in an orderly manner.  But there was a gentleman there who prayed that evening very loudly, in a commanding tone, commanding the evil spirits to cease their harassment of this lady, and he led the others to pray all at the same time with him, each in his or her own words, with hands outstretched towards the woman at the center of the circle.  As I said, the manner in which this was conducted--perhaps it was the spirit of it--made me uncomfortable, but I had no clear idea as to the reason.

I do not know for sure if there were any pictures taken.  Many people today have cell phones with cameras, and it is possible that someone did--but not likely while we were praying, as that was done with eyes closed, as is the usual custom.  I do know that I *personally* took no pictures of the event.  In any case, the woman, who had had to be assisted coming into the home, walked easily on her own two feet at the end of the meeting.  And all were rejoicing at the miracle.

Three days later we received tragic news.  The woman had died.

I believe the "miracle" was a temporary one--a trick of Satan to deceive us, and that all the while, Satan had his grip on the situation.

Remember, Jesus' own disciples were unable to cast out the demons from the demon-possessed boy at the foot of the mountain while their master was not with them.  Jesus later answered their question as to the reason for this by saying:

> Howbeit this kind goeth not out but by prayer and fasting. (Matthew
> 17:21, KJV)
>
> And he said unto them, This kind can come forth by nothing, but by
> prayer and fasting. (Mark 9:29, KJV)

We may have prayed in that meeting, but we certainly had not fasted.  We had not even known ahead of the meeting that the lady would be attending it.  And there was, as it were, an uneasy spirit of confusion present in the meeting in place of God's sweet spirit of truth, order, and love.

I share this as a warning: Not every "miracle," even one that may be captured on camera, is a miracle indeed.  Satan and his angels can mimic the miracles of God just as the servants of Pharaoh copied the miracles that Moses did in Egypt by God's power (see Exodus 7:11, 22).  Beware of seeking miracles of the wrong source--as they will never have lasting benefit, but will always worsen one's situation in the end.

Comment: Counterpoint: Jesus Himself says that Satan doesn't cast out demons, because that would be stupid of him to do - a kingdom divided against itself cannot stand. https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2012%3A22-32%2CLuke%2011%3A14-23&version=NIV

Comment: @nick012000 I see that not as a counterpoint, but in full agreement with what I shared.  That is the point.  No demon was cast out.  A demon-possessed person may not always foam and rage at the mouth, and sometimes the demons will do other things to promote their cause.