# Has an angel or a demon ever been recorded on camera?

Tags: history, angels, demons, technology

Simple question: has an angel or a demon ever been recorded on camera? I'm open to answers from any Christian groups/denominations.

---

Related questions:

- [Has a healing miracle ever been recorded on camera?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/83624/50422)
- [How do continuationists explain the absence of video recordings of undeniable miracles?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/84586/50422)

Comment: What is the point of questions like this? Someone somewhere might claim to have a photo of an angel or demon. No one else is going to be convinced. The only thing you could learn from a question like this is the trivia of whether anyone has ever claimed to have a photo of an angel or demon, which of course is almost certainly true (think of all the ghost hunter shows etc., people will claim anything!) Please, only ask questions which will reveal matters concerning the theology and practice of Christian groups.

Comment: @curiousdannii - Why didn't you react the same way to [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/83624/50422)?

Comment: Don't deflect by asking about other questions. There is of course a huge difference, in that healing miracles happen to physical bodies, and some Christians claim they are evidence of God's work. Are there Christians who claim angels/demons should be photographable? Is there any group with a theological basis which claims they should be photographable? Most Christian don't even think we can see them! (Most of the time I mean. Angels have appeared to people in the past, but we don't see them normally, if they're still around at all.)

Comment: How would you know what an angel looks like ? In a photograph of a crowd, how would you pick out an angel ? (They do not have wings and halos.) This is 100% opinion-based. There are YouTube videos which may, or may not, show angelic activity, but it is so easy to fake both still and moving images these days that none of it is reliable.

Comment: @curiousdannii: `There is of course a huge difference, in that healing miracles happen to physical bodies, and some Christians claim they are evidence of God's work` - but the same thing could be said of demons/angels manifesting in the physical realm, right? `Are there Christians who claim angels/demons should be photographable? Is there any group with a theological basis which claims they should be photographable?` - Again, same questions could be asked about healing miracles (in fact, see [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/84586/50422)).

Comment: @NigelJ - a similar "appeal to the fake" argument can be used to argue against the healing miracles question.

Comment: Yes, I agree. One could verify a sighting by witness statements and not rely merely on images. Similarly, one could verify a healing by competent witnesses and not merely rely on hearsay. But your question stipulates 'camera' so that is the criterion you have set.

Comment: Agree with curiousdannii that this question is different than the healing one.  1) But if you ask whether there are video of *humans possessed by demons*, it's a lot more productive as Catholic exorcists can discern their presence in the possessed victims.  Still, Catholic exorcists would not allow exorcism sessions to be videotaped.  2) Question on video of good angels is not productive since good angels wouldn't possess a human and if they appear in bodily form, they wouldn't pre-announce their appearance.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple: `Agree with curiousdannii that this question is different than the healing one.` - Of course it is different, otherwise this would have been closed as a duplicate of the other one.

Answer (score 1):

**Has an angel or a demon ever been recorded on camera?**

No Angel or Demon has ever been recognized as being recorded on camera.

How can something incorporeal such as an angelic being be recorded on camera as being a corporal being such as a man?

Any claim to the contrary would remain in the realm of skepticism and would be deemed by most Christian denominations as untrue.

YouTube videos may make such claims, but I would venture to say that they would not hold up to any valid scientific scrutiny and/or serious ecclesiastical investigations into the subject matter.

Angels, whether good or evil are spiritual being and can not be photographed. They have no physical form. They neither walk or consume food in order to maintain their existence. Neither do they speak as we do on earth.

> Angels manifest knowledge to one another, and to this extent they "speak" to one another. But the speech of angels is not a matter of sounds or of uttered words. The speech of angels is a direct communication of knowledge from spirit to spirit. - [The Speech of Angels](https://www.jesus-passion.com/angels.htm)